# How to access sybase with PERL

Tags: perl, sybase

Here is what I have so far.  I can not create the db connection.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
require "sybutil.pl";
use Sybase::DBlib;
use DBI;
my $dbhandle=&opendb;
sub opendb{
    my $server ="abc.nam.aa.net";
    my $user = "sam";
    my $password = "abc123";
    #print "Connecting to $server as $user and $password\n";
    my $dbfh= new Sybase::DBlib($user, $password, $server);
    if(!defined($dbfh)) {
        die("Cannot connect to server.\n");
    }
    printf "Open database '%s' with id '%s' successful\n", $server, $user;
    return $dbfh;
}
```

How do I access sybase with PERL?

Comment: You're using DBI, but not actually putting it to use.  Do you *need* Sybase::DBlib?  Or can you live with using DBI in conjunction with DBD::sybase?  ` use DBI;

    $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:", $user, $passwd);`

Comment: yes, i can romove DBI. I have to use Sybase::DBlib to access database, but i don't know the format of $server, does it include port or just host name, do you have any sample about this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, the format for $server, should be the same as the entry in the interfaces file ($SYBASE/interfaces or %SYBASE%/sql.ini) for that particular server.  It's ususally the same value as returned by the query `select @@servername`

The hostname/ip and port are listed in the interfaces file, and the Sybase libraries will use that file to do the lookup.

More information on this as well as code samples can be found at [Michael Peppler's site](http://www.peppler.org/sybperl/sybperl.html).  Michael maintains the Sybperl mailing list, and really has a great amount of information on his site.